# toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, json

My code to create a new JSONObject and write to a file:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "abcd");
obj.put("age", new Integer(100));
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add("msg 1");
list.add("msg 2");
list.add("msg 3");
obj.put("messages", list);
try {
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\test.json");
    file.write(obj.toJSONString());
    file.flush();
    file.close();    
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.print(obj);
```

My problem is at

```
file.write(obj.toJSONString());
```

It says that

> The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject.

Am I missing any library? Or am I going about it wrong? Is there alternative way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you meants `obj.toString()`?

Comment: I tried it but gives me errror.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ..... Can't post entire log.

Comment: That's a build error preventing the display of your real exception: it says it can't load the class `NestableRuntimeException` from Apache commons lang. You need to fix that first just to be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Make sure that the library exist in your app. Also, it would be helpful to include the `import` statements that you have

Comment: I didn't get @MarkoTopolnik . How to fix it? Multithreader I have both commonlang and Json library added to project and imported too.

Comment: @Multithreader Import statements cannot play a role here. The compiler had no trouble finding the class, otherwise this error would not happen at runtime. OP, add the commons-lang jar to your runtime classpath.

Comment: Note that the above error is *not* saying that NestableRuntimeException cannot be found, but rather that there is some sort of version mismatch or that class in turn cannot find another class.  (Hint: Be sure to look further down in the exception trace for another error that may be the true cause.)

Comment: logcat error is shown only when i use **obj.toString();** From where I learned above code uses **obj.toJSONString()**. So please tell me only, why "The method toJSONString() is undefined for the type JSONObject" is shown?

Comment: Your compile fails when you use toJSONString, so you never get far enough to get the other error.  If you have documentation showing two different names for the method that suggests that you've mixed up two different library versions and that is the root of your problem.

Comment: likely a corrupt jar. remove commons-lang from your maven dir and populate again

Answer (score 11):

The [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) class doesn't have a `toJSONString()` method. Instead it overrides the [`toString()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29) method to generate json.

To get the json representation of the object, simply use `obj.toString()`.

Comment: but the document says another story. Have a look at http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#valueToString(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @blackSmith link has gone.

Comment: @zionpi : I'm not sure to which location it has been moved. But I think http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html should still has the information.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same question, if you want to use `toJSONString()` you need to import `json-simple-1.1.jar` library.

Answer (score 1):

The method `toJSONString()` is from `json-simple` but I guess you are using `org.json`.

`org.json` have an alternative to `toJSONString()`.
You can simply use: `obj.toString(1)`.

The difference to the `toString()` method is, that if you pass "1" as parameter `org.json` automatically will format and beautify your `JSON`.
So you don't have only one single compressed line of `JSON` in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stringifying the JsonObject will not work. Using json-simple 3.1.0, `JsonObject.toString()` will not write the object as valid JSON.

Given the JSON Object as:

```
JsonObject my_obj = new JsonObject();
my_obj.put("a", 1);
my_obj.put("b", "z");
my_obj.put("c", true);
```

```
file.write(my_obj.toString());
```

Will save as

```
{a=1, b=z, c=true}
```

Which is not valid JSON.

To fix this, you need to use the `Jsoner`.

**Working Example**

```java
import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonObject;
import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.Jsoner;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JsonObject my_obj = new JsonObject();
        my_obj.put("a", 1);
        my_obj.put("b", "z");
        my_obj.put("c", true);

        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("test.json"));
            Jsoner.serialize(my_obj, writer);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which saves as

```
{"a":1,"b":"z","c":true}
```

Which is valid JSON.